# Moving camera-attached surface view

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am trying to figure out how to move the x y coordinates of a surface view that is attached to a camera object (or maybe it's the camera that is attached to the surface view, I'm not sure how that wording should go :P).

What I mean by that is - imagine an app that displays a map: The map image is much bigger than the screen, and you might be able to "move" the map image by swiping your finger across the screen. I want this same functionality (not the swipe part mind you), and how I imagine it working is that I zoom the camera a little bit to make it bigger than the screen, and then I want to be able to adjust it's position programmatically so that I can shift the view around as I want, looking at different sections of the view. I'm just not quite sure how to get there.

Could someone kindly point me in a right direction?

I have a FrameLayout, within that is a SurfaceView. In the code I have a Camera object, a SurfaceView object, and a SurfaceHolder object. I grab the SurfaceView using findViewById, and from that I use the getHolder() method of the SurfaceView class to get the SurfaceHolder, and then with the Camera object I call setPreviewDisplay(holder) and pass it the SurfaceHolder object. Fairly straightforward stuff :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The system compositor can do it, but I'm not sure if there's a way for an app to tell the Window Manager what it wants.

The cleanest approach is probably to send the Camera output to a SurfaceTexture, and then render the texture with OpenGL ES.  That would allow you full freedom to move, zoom, rotate, whatever.  [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) has a few examples, though none is a perfect fit for what you want (it's on the to-do list though).  "Show + capture camera" is close, but it always uses a full-size rect.

**Update:** Grafika now does this.  See the "Texture from Camera" activity.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you much, I'll take a look and report back with findings :)